# android firebase 12.0.0 - mAuth.getCurrentUser().getProvider() method is removed, how to get provider names?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

in `firebase_version = '11.8.0'` there was a method called  `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getProviders()` i could call to get the list of provider names. so for email provider it was "password" and for facebook is was "facebook.com", etc

the method call was like this:

```
final FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser()

    for (String provider : this.currentUser.getProviders()) {
      //i was looping over all the providers this way, and then storing the provider string in my db
    }
```

but now in the latest `firebase_version = '12.0.0'` the method `getProviders()` is not available. 
        How can i get the provider names as string ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [FirebaseUser.getProviderData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getProviderData()).  It returns a list of [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo), each contains a string Provider ID.

For example:

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    List<? extends UserInfo> infos = user.getProviderData();
    for (UserInfo ui : infos) {
        if (ui.getProviderId().equals(GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i guess this a is substitute for it. i'll change the call to getProviderId instead of getProvider. but the thing is there use to be two methods, getProvider() and getProviderId(). this is why im confused.  but thanks for the response.

Comment: Although `getProviders()` is a public method in the pre-12.0.0 SDK, I don't recall ever seeing it in the documentation and web searches don't find much.  Maybe it was not intended to be part of the API and was deleted from 12.0.0 without a deprecation phase.

Comment: `getProviderId()` always returns "firebase" for google, facebook, etc. login cases that I tried. So, using `getProviderData().get(0).getProviderId()` seems like the working way.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I am able to get provider id of logged in user.
You can use similar provider ids which are shared by iOS developers. Like
google.com, password, microsoft.com, Facebook.com etc

[image]

private void providerId() {
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

```
if (user != null) {
    String providerID = user.getProviderData().get(1).getProviderId();
    switch (providerID) {
        case "google.com":
            break;
        case "password":
            break;
        case "microsoft.com":
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}