# Best method to replace "user.getProviders()" after the update of version 12.0.0

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Prior to version 12, I had the following code snippet to obtain the current authenticated login provider ID.

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String provider = user.getProviders().get(0);
```

which returned the current auth ID provider "Password, google.com, facebook.com...."

however after the update to Firebase version 12, the method "getProviders" was removed from the SDK.

```
user.getProviderId()
```

always returns the value "firebase" however the method

```
user.getProviderData().get(1).getProviderId()
```

it functioning in the same old way, is there any other method to obtain the same results ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android firebase 12.0.0 - mAuth.getCurrentUser()getProvider() method is removed, how to get provider names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49484003/android-firebase-12-0-0-mauth-getcurrentusergetprovider-method-is-removed)

Comment: yeah but that does not answer my question, because i hate to use user.getProviderData().get(1).getProviderId()  is there any other method ? I dont need to compare, I just need the current provider ID.

Comment: ohh okay which method do you like to use?

Comment: in fact this is a flaw in Firebase we need a new method that returns the last auth provider see the issue here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/329